# qsettings different results

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QSettings to try and figure out if an INI is valid.(using status() to check) I made a purposefully invalid INI file and loaded it in. The first time the code is called, it returns invalid, but every time after that, it returns valid. Is this a bug in my code?

Comment: Can you paste your code and the file?

Comment: yep...this is the method:
http://pastebin.ca/1802323

and the file is:
http://pastebin.ca/1802322

Answer (score 1):

It's a  **Qt bug** caused by some global state.  Note that the difference in results happens whether or not you call `delete` on your QSettings object, which you should. Here's a brief summary of what happens on the first run:

1. The result code is set to `NoError`.
2. A global cache is checked to see if your file is present
3. Your file isn't present the first time, so it's parsed on `qsettings.cpp` line 1530 (Qt-4.6.2)
4. Parsing results in an error and the result code is set (see `qsettings.cpp` line 1552).
5. The error result code is returned.

And the second run is different:

1. The result code is set to `NoError`.
2. A global cache is checked, your file is present.
3. The file size and timestamp are checked to see if the file has changed (see `qsettings.cpp` line 1424).
4. The result code is returned, which happens to be `NoError` -- the file was assumed to have been parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Checked your code, you need to delete the file object before returning.

Apart from that, your code uses the `QSettings::QSettings(fileName, format)` c'tor to open an ini-file. That call ends in the function `QConfFile::fromName` (implemented in [qsettings.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/master/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp)). As I read it (there are a few macros and such that I decided not to follow), the file is not re-opened if the file already is open (i.e. you have not deleted the object since the last time). Thus the status will be ok the second time around.